# How do you stack svgs on top of each other that are generated from a for loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, d3.js, svg

This is what I have so far, the problem is that each time the svg is generated they don't stack on top of each other to form the illusion of an animation but instead they stack next to each other or below, does anyone know how to fix this? Also does anyone know how I can make the circle appear from the bottom of the container instead of the top? Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Animation</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style> 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      </svg>
    <script>

  var height1 = 0;

    for (let height1 = 0; height1 < 20; height1 ++) {
    setTimeout(function timer(){
      console.log(height1)

      //make SVG container
      var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                        .attr("width", 100)
                                        .attr("height", height1);
      //Draw circle 
      var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
                              .attr("cx", 50)
                              .attr("cy", 50)
                              .attr("r", 50);
    }, height1*500)


    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are trying to do (which is not clear at all, mainly because there are many alternatives to properly creating an animation), the problem with your code is that you are appending a new SVG at every loop.

Instead of that, append the SVG just once and change its height:

```js
var height1 = 0;
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100);

for (let height1 = 0; height1 < 20; height1++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {

    //make SVG container
    svgContainer.attr("height", height1);
    //Draw circle 
    var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 50)
      .attr("cy", 50)
      .attr("r", 50);
  }, height1 * 500)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

On the other hand, if you really want to append a SVG at every loop and end up with a bunch of SVGs on top of each other (for whatever reason, it's not my place to judge), then you have to use `position: absolute`:

```js
  var height1 = 0;

  for (let height1 = 0; height1 < 20; height1++) {
    setTimeout(function timer() {

      //make SVG container
      var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", height1);
      //Draw circle 
      var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .attr("r", 50);
    }, height1 * 500)
  }
```

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement Gerardo Furtado’s response, pay attention to those two `height1` variables in your script. I guess you didn’t intend to have two of them.

One is declared with `var` at the top scope of your script; the other one is declared with `let` and is local to your loop. I insist on the point that they are two different variables, and I suggest you remove the one you declared with `var`.